# Differences between LAM MPI and OpenMPI

Tags: mpi, openmpi

I was wondering how these two are related to each other.
Could anyone here explain?

Cheers.

Comment: Can you specify? What kind of differences do you have in mind?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are two implementations of the [MPI standard](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/).   In the late 90s and early 2000s, there were many different MPI implementations, and the implementors started to realize they were all re-inventing the wheel; there was something of a consolidation.   The LAM/MPI team joined with the LA/MPI, FT-MPI, and eventually PACX-MPI teams to develop OpenMPI.   LAM MPI stopped being developed in 2007.   The code base for OpenMPI was completely new, but it brought in ideas and techniques from all the different teams.

Currently, the two major open-source MPI implementation code-bases are [OpenMPI](http://www.open-mpi.org/) and [MPICH2](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpich2/).

Comment: Thanks a bunch, Jonathan.
This is the kind of answer I was looking for.